# Wie funktioniert Satzstellung im Deutschen?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, word-order, question

Ich habe eine Frage zur Satzstellung im Deutschen.

Wieso kann ich nicht sagen

- 1) "...hinzu wollte ich noch eine Sprache lernen und ich **habe einfach mich** für Deutsch entschieden."

Wieso muss es heißen > "**habe mich einfach**" (Reflexivpronomen + Adverb)

- 2) "Im Kino **sie haben sich** auf Stühle gesetzt."

  > "**haben sie sich**". Wieso darf das Pronomen "sie" nicht vor "haben" stehen?
- 3) "Im Ersten Bild, **man sieht, dass** ..."

  > "**sieht man, dass**"; wieso darf "man" nicht an erster Stelle stehen?

Answer (score 7):

1) Partikel wie *ja*, *eben*, *einfach* usw. beziehen sich auf den Satzteil, welcher direkt darauf folgt.

*Ich habe einfach mich für Deutsch entschieden.* ist falsch, denn es bedeutet nicht das, was du ausdrücken willst. Denn du willst ja schreiben, dass es Alternativen zu Deutsch gab, und nicht etwa, dass es Alternativen zu dir gab. Beim Verb *sich entscheiden* ist das eindeutig, weil du ja explizit selbst etwas tust.

Das gilt für die meisten reflexiven Verben. Z.B. bei den Verben *sich anbieten* und *sich vorschlagen* sind aber dennoch beide Varianten möglich:

> Ich habe mich einfach angeboten. (Ich habe nicht auf eine Bitte gewartet.)
>
> Ich habe einfach mich angeboten. (Ich habe nicht darauf gewartet, dass sich jemand anders meldet.)

Bei nicht-reflexiven Verben geht praktisch immer beides:

> Sie hat ihn einfach geküsst. (Sie hat nicht lange überlegt, was sie sonst tun sollte.)
>
> Sie hat einfach ihn geküsst. (Sie hat nicht lange überlegt, wen sie sonst küssen sollte.)

Partikel, die sich nicht auf Verben beziehen, sind natürlich völlig problemlos überall unterzubringen.

> Ich bin einfach eine Stunde später mit dem Bus gefahren. (Es war kein Problem, eine Stunde später zu fahren.)
>
> Ich bin eine Stunde später einfach mit dem Bus gefahren. (Es war kein Problem, mit dem Bus zu fahren.)
>
> Er hat einfach im Park auf sie gewartet. (Es war kein Problem, im Park zu warten.)
>
> Er hat im Park einfach auf sie gewartet. (Es war kein Problem, auf sie zu warten.)

---

2) Hier ist die Regel: Das finite Verb steht im Hauptsatz an zweiter Position.

> Sie haben sich im Kino auf Stühle gesetzt.
>
> Sie haben sich auf Stühle im Kino gesetzt.
>
> Im Kino haben sie sich auf Stühle gesetzt.

Im letzten Beispiel steht *im Kino* an erster Position. Also muss das Subjekt *sie* hinter das finite Verb *haben*.

3) Genau wie in 2)

> Man sieht im ersten Bild, dass
>
> Im ersten Bild sieht man, dass …